# Can I use Command Substitution with exit status, rather than stdout?

Tags: linux, bash

**Given:**

```
tty --quiet
echo $?
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

...and...

```
tty --quiet && echo foo || echo bar
```

> ```
> foo
> ```

Why is this false?

```
[ $(tty --quiet) ] && echo foo || echo bar
```

> ```
> bar
> ```

That is, why is the exit status of the command substitution non-zero?

Is it because the command above has no stdout output?  Or am I doing something wrong with spaces / spacing?

I [understand](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) that for `$(command)`, bash  performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command.

However, what I **want** to do is *use the exit status from* `$(command)` *as a logic gate for a series of complex operations* (substituted by `echo`), as below:

```
[ $(command1) ] && {
    [ $(command2) ] && {
        echo "Conditions 1 and 2 are true."
      } || {
        echo "Condition 1 is true.  Condition 2 is false."
    }
  } || {
    [ $(command3) ] && {
        echo "Condition 1 is false.  Condition 3 is true."
      } || {
        echo "Conditions 1 and 3 are false."
    }
}
```

---

btw my [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) involves mucking around with the settings of interactive login shells, which I know is better solved like [THIS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch#26782) but for now I need to modify this crap script and it uses `tty --quiet` a lot, frown.

Anyway, if Command Substitution just doesn't work the way I want, I can write it as...

```
if [ $(command1) ] ; then
  if [ $(command2) ] ; then
```

...etc. but this approach seems much more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You evaluate the return status with:

```
if tty --quiet; then ...
```

When you do `if [ $(tty --quiet) ]`, it is equivalent to `if [ ]`, which evaluates to false.  (The man page states: 'An omitted EXPRESSION defaults to false').  It sounds like you don't want command substitution at all, but just want to execute the command.  In other words, you want:

```
command1 && {
    command2 && {
        echo "Conditions 1 and 2 are true."
      } || {
        echo "Condition 1 is true.  Condition 2 is false."
    }
  } || {
    command3 && {
        echo "Condition 1 is false.  Condition 3 is true."
      } || {
        echo "Conditions 1 and 3 are false."
    }
}
```

Comment: "It sounds like you don't want command substitution at all, but just want to execute the command" -- exactly correct, thank you.  I was stuck on one idea.  Hooray for my first ever question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

`[ $(tty --quiet) ]` tests if the result of `tty` is an empty string or not. The only exit status involved is that of `[` itself; the exit status of `tty` is ignored.

You simply want

```
if command1; then
   if command2; then
       echo "1 and 2 are true"
   else
       echo "1 is true; 2 is false"
   fi
elif command3; then
    echo "1 is false; 3 is true"
else
    echo "1 and 3 are false"
fi
```